# How to disable WCF Test Client while hosting services in a managed application?

Tags: wcf, self-hosting, wcftestclient

I am hosting WCF services in a console application and i am trying to use the same endpoint address configured in the service config file in my host application. But when ever i am trying to run the application i am getting AddressAlreadyInUse exception because of WCF Test Client is consuming those ports. So i wanted to disable automatice hosting in the WCF test client while debugging self hosting. 
I tried disabling WCFTestClient.exe startup through project property section but still it's not working. 
Have a look of the snapshot: 
[image]